# Reducing lag on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sLGe/3/

I am concerned that it will be very laggy doing this because it's monitoring `scroll`. I saw mention on my other question of debouncing a bit like this:

```
var scrollTimeout,
    callback = function () {  
        /// Do your things here
    };

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (scrollTimeout)
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);

    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(callback, 40);

});
```

Can anyone tell me if this is a good idea and how it might be integrated.

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For smooth results, I would stick with this firing on every scroll event. Otherwise there would be a delay before sticking or unsticking.

However, you can improve the performance of your function by caching the jQuery collections, and only sticking / unsticking if needed.

Here's a simple example module using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9sLGe/9/

```
(function() {
  var $select = $('#select');
  var $window = $(window);
  var isFixed = false;
  var init = $('#select').offset().top;

  $window.scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
      isFixed = true;
      $select.css({
        top: 0,
        position: 'fixed'
      });
      console.log("fixed");
    } else if (currentScrollTop <= init && isFixed === true) {
      isFixed = false;
      $select.css('position', 'relative');
      console.log("unfixed");
    }
  });
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is not really one of rapid-firing events (although debouncing will certainly help, at the cost of a slight lack of responsiveness/immediateness), but more of one that you are changing CSS properties *every single time* the event fires.

You should consider having a flag like "isStickified", and use your `if` condition to change that flag. If, and only if, the flag *changes*, that is when you should set the CSS to update. This will be much more efficient.